# Redirect direct access to COM-Domain to English site

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect a direct access to the website to its English content. Do you see any problem or improvement of my code?

```
/* 
 * Load English page if *.com domain
 */
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$extension = pathinfo($domain, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($extension == "com" &&
   !preg_match('/'.$domain.'/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) &&
   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/'){

        header('Location: /en/');
        exit;

}
```

One problem I see is that if the users browser has `HTTP_REFERER` deactivated he couldn't access to `http://domain.com`. Is there a better solution?

---

### EDIT

Here example of the usage:

- direct access to `http://domain.com` should be forwarded to `http://domain.com/en/`
- If the the user clicks the link to the base `<a href='/'>home</a>` or `<a href='http://domain.com'>home</a>` it should not be redirected.

Comment: What web server are you using? This function is better served by using the web server's URL rewriting features.  It would help if you identify exact examples of input URL and the URL they should be redirected to under exactly what circumstances.

Comment: I'm using Apache... How do you suggest it with .htaccess ?

Comment: Please post example URLs, but the input URL, what it should be redirected to, and an example of an input URL that should not be redirected.

Comment: I added an example of the usage. Just the direct access to the domain should be redirected...